# How do I give PHP write access to a directory while creating and writing a file?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use PHP to create a file and write in it some text from textfiles coming from the page before, but it isn't working. I am assuming this is because it doesn't have write access. I tried to test if this was the problem by making the folder chmod 0755,but nothing happened. Maybe I do have an error in the code?

As you may notice, I would like this php to redirect to another page, while executing the code. Maybe is this the problem I have?

Thank you very much, this is a school project quite important ^^'

```
<?php
$fitxer = "/Users/Usuario/Desktop/blog.txt";
$nom = $_POST["usuari"];
$msg = $_POST["contrasenya"];

chmod("/Users/Usuario/Desktop/blog.txt", 0755);
file_put_contents($fitxer, "$nom: $msg\n", FILE_APPEND);
header('Location: /Users/Usuario/Desktop/prova.html');
```

?>
**Edit 1:** I'm using windows 7, and the php code is displayed in the webpage as html instead of just executing, as seen in the next image:

[image]

Comment: if the php user isn't the owner of the file (or hasn't sufficiant rights already), you cannot chmod it to get more rights.

Comment: I'd remove the header for now, test what the returns are, see if you get errors. You can use [fileperms()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) to check if you got write-access or not.

Comment: The problem is that I don't actually know if it has enough powers or not. When I try to execute the code directly to the web page, instead of moving me to the next webpage, it shows me this code as if it was html, when it shouldn't.

Comment: Your code is not working because it isn't even running. Have you installed PHP in your computer? You're also using a lot of Unix conventions that can't work if you actually run Windows :-?

Comment: I should have php in my computer. What Unix convertions I'm using? I'm kinda new at programming :/

Comment: File system paths like `/Users/Usuario/Desktop` (instead of `C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop`) or `chmod 0755`. And, yes, you always need to install any tool you want to use. Operating systems don't bundle all the programs that exist ;-)